# While loop not looping (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

Simple question here. I am slowly building a to do list program. Whilst you do not quit I would like to the program to keep looping. But it keeps asking 'What is the to do text' after it is inputted?

Whereas I would like it to loop back to the beginning 'What would you like to do' so I can add additional functions such as:
list the to do's
Delete a to do

Code below:

```
while (input.toLowerCase() !== 'quit') {

    const list = [];

    if (input === 'new') {
        let todo = prompt('What is the to do text')
        list.push(todo);
        
    }

    }
```

Comment: If the value of input is not "new" or "quit" it will loop for ever. Try putting `console.log` at a couple of points in your program you might understand whats happening

Comment: [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)

Comment: Your loop runs as long as input does not equal "quit". In order to get out of this loop, at some point inside the loop, you need to set the value of input to "quit" or use one of the commands that forces the loop to break. Once you are in your loop, input never changes, so the behavior never changes.

Comment: The list does not grow; each loop iteration re-declares `list` initializes it to `[]`. **And** it is **NOT** visible outside the loop. Also if `input` is not changing within the loop, if ever control enters the loop, there's no getting out of it, **EVER**!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define input first and i would put the list outside the while loop because if you dont the list get overwritten each time.

```
let input = ''
const list = [];
while (input.toLowerCase() !== 'quit') {
    input = prompt('What do you want to do?')
    if (input === 'new') {
        let todo = prompt('What is the to do text')
        list.push(todo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Once I input into the 'what is to do text' it asks that question again. Rather than looping back to the 'What would you like to do'